# How to add parameters to a method in java

Tags: java, parameters, parameter-passing

For example, I have a User class

```
public class User{

public void createInfo(String username, int age, string address){

  JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
  json.put("username", "xxxx");
  json.put("age", 20);
  json.put("address", "xxxxxx");
  System.out.print(json.toJSONString());
  }

public static void main(String[] args) {

     User user = new User();
     user.createInfo("xxxx", 11, 112222);
  }
}
```

For username, age and address, they are the required field of this method. Now I want to add some optional fields to this reult.
For example, I want to add a phoneNumber field. How to do that like

```
user.createInfo("xxxx", 11, 112222).addPhoneNumber(1234566)
```

Then the phone number will be added to the json data?

Comment: there is not optional parameter in java. you must overload it and call last one and do your additional thing that you need.

Comment: you mean the only way is createInfo(String username, int age, string address, int phoneNumber)

Comment: yes. then call createInfo() to do some of works for you instead of copy code and do additional work. it is better to return JSONObject as a result of object so you can create second `createInfo()` easily and it is more related to its name. it is not good to print something in a method. do print else where you want because maybe you don't want to print something immediately. if you want to add more optional parameter, maybe using some techniques like @AndrewTobilko is good. you can use new feature like Map.of to send parameters too.

Comment: You can use the builder pattern

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class User{

  private String username;
  private Integer age;
  private String address;
  private String phone;

  public User addPhoneNumber(String phone){
      this.phone = phone;
      return this;
  }

  public User createInfo(String username, int age, String address){

      this.username =  username;
      this.age = age;
      this.address = address;

      return this;
  }

  public String generateJsonText(){
      JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
      if (username != null) json.put("username", username);
      if (age != null) json.put("age", age);
      if (address != null) json.put("address", address);
      if (phone != null) json.put("phone ", phone );
      return json.toJSONString();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
     User user = new User();
     String json = user.createInfo("xxxx", 11, 112222).addPhoneNumber("1234567").generateJsonText();
  }
}
```

It is called **BuilderPattern**, search about it.
Any Question?

Comment: Thank you. That's what I want.

Comment: @HenlenLee if you've got a new optional field, you would require to modify this builder (at least, add a new method and field).

Comment: I see. Appreciate for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the varargs approach, this can be called like:

```
myMethod("user", 12, "address", "optional1", "optional2");



public void myMethod(String username, int age, String address, String... foo ) {
     System.out.println(foo[0] + foo[1]);
}
```